# Javascript match one regex, but not another

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I find all words in string which 
match one expression:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{4,}/
```

but do not match another one:

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])\1+[a-zA-Z]\b/
```

Something like pseudocode:

```
string.match( (first_expression) && ( ! second_expression) )
```

Comment: Don't use `[A-z]`, use `[a-zA-Z]` as in your first expression. `[A-z]` will match more than just letters.

Comment: I believe `\w` also works in this instance

Comment: `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z_\d]` AFAIK.

Comment: You are right F.J, fixed this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
string.match(/[a-zA-Z]{4,}/) && !string.match(/\b[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])\1+[a-zA-Z]\b/)
```

But if you'd like to combine the patterns, you can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?!...)`), like this:

```
string.match(/^(?!.*\b[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])\1+[a-zA-Z]\b).*[a-zA-Z]{4,}.*$/)
```

But this will reject the whole string if it finds the second pattern—e.g.`"fooz barz"` will return `null`.

To ensure the words you find do not match the other pattern, try this:

```
string.match(/\b(?![a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])\1+[a-zA-Z]\b)[a-zA-Z]{4,}\b/)
```

In this case, `"fooz barz"` will return `"barz"`.

Note that this can be cleaned up a bit by using the case insensitive flag (`i`):

```
string.match(/\b(?![a-z]([a-z])\1+[a-z]\b)[a-z]{4,}\b/i)
```

Comment: This is more elegant than my solution.

Comment: If you're just checking for validity, I'd use `test`.

Comment: Yep, the last one do the job! With small fix on my side - I've changed [A-z] to [A-Za-z]. BIG THX!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(string.match(first_expression))
{
    if(!string.match(second_expression))
    {
        //Do something important
    }
}
```

This should match what you want and not what you don't.